# Python 3 - Adding string numbers to a list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

So if the user input is:
user = input('Enter numbers here in the following format "10 12 14": ')

then the user inputs numbers 10 11 12 in that exact way, not separated by commas, and all in one string separated by spaces, how can i add the numbers to a list and then convert them to int instead of string

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve this would be by the following,

```
list(map(int,input('Enter Numbers: ').split()))
```

This will ask the user for numbers to enter which will return back a `str` object as the user has entered them via [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input). The `split` call at the end, returns a comma separated list containing those numbers. They are still considered `str` at this point.

The next [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#map) function accepts a `fnc` and `list` arguments, which will apply the `fnc` argument to each item within the `list`. In this case, it will cast each value in the `list` of `str` objects to an `int` type.

The last step would be to convert the `map` object we had created into a `list` via the [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#list) call.

Comment: @Torched90 As I am learning Python in the process, if you revamp this answer, please feel free to leave a comment here regarding so. I'd be interested in learning/seeing other approaches that was taken to arrive to the same answer.